# Change back office language from Russian to English in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I am trying to work on my Prestashop back office and the language is set to Russian which I don't understand. I would like to change the language to English and I have tried Translating the  steps given on this forum and others into Russian but Google Translate does not seem to help here. Giving the procedure in Russian or how to configure that from the files will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may run into a similar problem next time, I solved this by looking for 'ЛОКАЛИЗАЦИЯ' on the left bar which is an equivalent for 'My preferences' and I selected 'Язык' which translates to 'Language' and the active languages showed up. Under the enable button named 'Энаблед' I disabled Russian which was already active.